# Can anyone recommend a budget software setups for live guitar gigs?

Tags: music-production, music-composing

Please recommend software for setting up an electric guitar for live gigs.

Excluding the guitar is there any kind of hardware required to change the guitar effects?

How to integrate software such that we can manually change the effect **mid-song** fast without disturbing the rhythm?

Is there any chance I can make one within $700 total cost?

OS preferred is Windows 8+ but any Linux based solution is also welcome if it is not too difficult to setup.

Comment: Are there no answers?